# Cheap Windows Computer for Corporate VPN Access?

Tags: mini-pc

I need to VPN into my company's network, and then RDP into some Windows Servers.  Corporate IT seems very Windows-focused, and there's no MacOS client for the VPN software.

So I'm wondering if I could pick up one of those really cheap headless Windows machines such as the HP Pavilion Mini or the Asus VivoMini (or even an Intel Compute Stick) just for VPN'ing.

Would that work?  Would it have sufficient RAM/CPU to handle things?  Is this a stupid idea?

Comment: _Would it have sufficient RAM/CPU to handle things?_ well, what kind of things are we trying to do? RDP isn't particularly demanding and the experience rests more on the quality of your connection, but don't expect a raspberry pi to give as good an experience as a 4k video editing workstation pc

Comment: Do you have any requirements besides cost? Are you willing to pick something up used?